# Running raster calculator to build expression for ls factor?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I am trying to run a raster calculator, but it failed. I believe that ArcGIS 10 does not understand when I use the variable resolution.

What do I need to put in its place?

I took the equation from this sheet [USLE from North Carolina State University](http://skagit.meas.ncsu.edu/~helena/gmslab/erosion/usle.html) and checked on 2.3 for ArcGIS 8.1.

Here is the code I used:

```
Power (("flowaccNW")  *  resolution/22.1, 0.6) * Power(Sin("slope_degnw") *  0.01745)  / 0.09, 1.3
```

I am using ArcGIS 10 SP4 using the Map Algebra raster calculator.

Comment: If you look at the equation and it says "resolution" I took that from the sheet and ran with it and it failed. The ArcGIS said resolution does not defined.  It made me think that ArcGIS does not understand, so I instead put down 10 as it is the DEM with 10 m. Get it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type your resolution of raster, not "resolution". Also, don't type +*/= by keyboard. Use raster calculator buttons. 
Here's how to set the resolution of your raster :

1. Right-click your raster, and click **Properties**.
2. Go to **Source** tab.
3. Change **Cellsize(X,Y)** to set your resolution.
   [image]

Comment: It will not work, wetland.

Comment: your second power must have two parameters

Comment: see second power parentheses

Comment: like this 10,10 ?

Comment: I try this and it's work : Power("stream" * 10 / 22.1,0.6) * Power(Sin("slope") * 0.01745 / 0.09,1.3)

Comment: just type 10 for resolution

Comment: I wasn't sure what you mean but I already did put down 10 and it worked. Thanks !

Comment: see this link : http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009t00000004000000

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GISus-M to calculate LS-factor.
https://www2.ufrb.edu.br/gisus-m/